# Why are Mac and Linux Android ready but Windows isn't

Tags: android, linux, windows, macos, android-debug

According to the Android developers website ["If you're developing on Mac OS X or Linux, then you probably don't need to install a USB driver."](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html)

This is something that makes debugging Android application rather annoying on a Windows machine since there are so many different devices I want to be able to test with, and some of the drivers can be difficult to locate.

What is it that makes Mac OS X or Linux "probably" ready to go for all devices?

Is there any source where I can download and install all drivers?

Comment: My unhealthy suggestion would be installing VmWare on your Windows and put a Linux on it, if you're truly desperated.

Comment: I have VMWare already with Linux installed. It runs alright but once again that would be emulating a Unix based OS on Windows, but this time it would be Linux on Windows rather than Android on Windows. I was just curious if there are any one time installs to fix the annoying driver issue, but there doesn't appear to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found [a Git repo](https://github.com/koush/UniversalAdbDriver) which hosts an android_winusb.inf file that is kept up to date with the latest devices. Downloading the file should get a developer's Windows machine "probably" ready to go for testing on most if not all Android devices.

Answer (score 1):

Because their Kernel is same... (All three Android, Linux ,  Mac use the same System calls as they are built on the same Kernel)

But Windows Uses a Different Kernel system

Comment: I know their kernel's are all Unix based so that's what I figured. I guess I was hoping for some way to alleviate the development process for Android on Windows.

Comment: Yes, the linux kernel based emulator on Windows are slow since they have to emulate a Unix on Windows. I have downloaded the HAX Intel Emulator which is much much faster, but it does not allow for the Google API to be used on it. Anyways, I don't think the answer I want for my question exists :P

Answer (score 1):

> Also is there any source where I can download and install all drivers?

Yes you can, in my experience, there is only 1 driver, the one provided by google android sdk. You need only keep adding vendor_id/product_id/multi_instance to it's config file (android_winusb.inf):

> %CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_0BB4&PID_4E20&MI_04

You can get the vid/pid/mi info from device manager. You may need add to the x86 section or amd64 section or both depending what Windows system you intend to install this driver.

Comment: Awesome, I did not know about this. This still however would require me (or any other Android developer) to go lookup the vendor_id/product_id/multi_instance for each device they want to test so my next question would be is there a master android_winusb.inf file somewhere I can download? Ideally that is updated on a regular basis so that I can simply redownload, and that is available in both x86 and amd64 because the Windows machines I have to test on are both Intel x86 and amd64.